# Number formatting issue in iOS

Tags: ios, number-formatting

in my iOS app I try to populate a core data store the first time the app is executed. I am using following code in my AppDelegate.m file, I will show as example how I am creating one object of the entity:

```
     //creating new managedObject

     NSManagedObject *favoriteThing = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FavoriteThing" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];


    //extracting year,month and day from current date

    todayDate = [NSDate date];        
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:todayDate]; // Get necessary date components

    //converting components      
    NSNumber *yearBuscado = [NSNumber numberWithLong:[components year]];
    NSNumber *mesBuscado = [NSNumber numberWithLong:[components month]];
    NSNumber *diaBuscado = [NSNumber numberWithLong:[components day]];

    //populating managedObject

    [favoriteThing setValue:@"If done, swipe to right " forKey:@"thingName"];//String
    [favoriteThing setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] forKey:@"displayOrder"];//Integer32   
    [favoriteThing setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:yearBuscado] forKey:@"todoYear"];//Integer32
    [favoriteThing setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:mesBuscado] forKey:@"todoMonth"];//Integer32
    [favoriteThing setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:diaBuscado] forKey:@"todoDay"];//Integer32
    [favoriteThing setValue:@"Urgent" forKey:@"urgent"];//String
    [favoriteThing setValue:@"Yellow" forKey:@"color"];//String
    [favoriteThing setValue:@"Not deleted" forKey:@"isSemiDeleted"];//String
    [favoriteThing setValue:@"Not done" forKey:@"isDone"];//String
```

This is what is stored after launching the app the first time (extracted from SQLite manager):
[image]

What I need is to store the expected values for today (2014-01-04):

```
todoYear = 2014
todoMonth = 1
todoDay = 4
```

These three attributes are from type `Integer 32`
What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistakenly calling `numberWithInt` with a NSNumber object, instead call setValue directly with that NSNumber

```
todayDate = [NSDate date];        
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:todayDate]; // Get necessary date components

//converting components      
NSNumber *yearBuscado = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[components year]];
NSNumber *mesBuscado = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[components month]];
NSNumber *diaBuscado = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[components day]];

[favoriteThing setValue:yearBuscado forKey:@"todoYear"];//Integer32
[favoriteThing setValue:mesBuscado forKey:@"todoMonth"];//Integer32
[favoriteThing setValue:diaBuscado forKey:@"todoDay"];//Integer32
```

Also, you can generate the Model Classes from CoreData Model. So that you can set values to a `NSManagedObject` through `Properties` instead of doing Key-Value Coding.

Like

```
FavoriteThing *favoriteThing = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FavoriteThing" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[favoriteThing setBuscado: yearBuscado];
```

Comment: @mvasco Is that wat you are looking for? Issue rectified?

Comment: Not yet checked, but I guess your proposal is right, thank you. I will let you know as far as I check it...

Comment: Thank you, your first proposal is working as expected. Thank you very much. Have a nice day/night....

Answer (score 1):

Things have become easy with NSNumber in Modern objective C. you can define your number like:

```
NSNumber *todoYear = @2014;
NSNumber *todoMonth = @1;
NSNumber *todoDay = @4;
```

Compiler will take care of everything. Happy Coding :)

Look at these links for more info.
[NSNumber Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)
[modern Objective C Basics](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Basics_of_Modern_Objective-C)

**EDIT**
Use This:

```
NSNumber *yearBuscado = @([components year]);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to obtain the values from the current date, therefor I am using NSDateComponents...

Comment: how about NSNumber *todoYear =@([components year])  ??

Comment: Yeah, definitely thats a working answer. This would be helpful in future.. :)